# 2D platformer multiple rectangle collision cause jitter

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, collision-detection, collision-resolution

I posted this question two weeks ago: [2D platformer corner collision](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21365/2d-platformer-corner-collision) and I implemented NoobsArePeople2's solution.

Problem is, when player intersects two rectangles that are inside each other, he starts jittering. I don't know how to describe it so I made a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AYUGeuxM0c

In the first 4 or so seconds, you can see that when he collides with two rectangles that arent in each other or touching each other, everything works fine, but in the rest of the video, you can see that when player touches side, he starts to jitter (please note that because of fraps, my game was running at quarter of FPS I normaly have, so without fraps the jitter is much faster)

To give you idea how my collision rectangles look now, here is debug mode (each rectangle is randomly colored) [image]

I have couple of algortihms in place that merge rectangles into one (still need to do some work on that), but some simply cannot be merged. One example is the C object on the right. Right now it is made of 7 rectangles (will be 3 after I complete my algorithm) and when player slides on side of it, he starts to jitter.

I suspect problem is in my gravity, but Im not sure. I've spent 5 days on trying to fix this and Im lost.

Heres my code (slighty modified from platformer sample):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < playerCollisionRectangles.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 depth = Collision.GetIntersectionDepth(player.PlayerRectangleInWorld, playerCollisionRectangles[i]);
            if (depth != Vector2.Zero)
            {
                float absDepthX = Math.Abs(depth.X);
                float absDepthY = Math.Abs(depth.Y);

                // Resolve the collision along the shallow axis.
                if (absDepthY < absDepthX)
                {
                    // Resolve the collision along the Y axis.
                    player.PlayerPositionY += Convert.ToInt32(depth.Y);
                }
                else  
                {
                    // Resolve the collision along the X axis.
                    player.PlayerPositionX += Convert.ToInt32(depth.X);
                }
            }
        }
```

And here is my gravity code (very very simple):

```
        if (Gravity)
        {
            //for camera
            position.Y += 2;
            //position in world
            playerPositionY += 2;
        }
```

And lastly here is one of my methods to move player (i have similiar methods to move him left and up):

```
    public void MoveRight()
    {
        animate.Enabled = true;
        animate.Row = 0;
        position.X += speed;
        playerPositionX += speed;
    }
```

Comment: In what order are you handling input, applying gravity and doing collision detection? Should be in that order.

Comment: And when you change player.PlayerPositionX/Y inside the collision code, is the player.PlayerRectangleInWorld reflecting the change too?

Comment: Yes to both of those questions.

Comment: Hmm, and if you suspect gravity, have you tried disabling it to verify if it still occurs?

Comment: Just tried it, problem still persist.

Comment: This is strange. I've taken the platformer sample, and modified it to be as close as possible to what you have, and there's no problem. The only difference I see is that your player position seems to be stored as int, and you're converting to int there in the middle too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you are iterating through your collisions (playerCollisionRectangles) -- you are adjusting the position of your player more than once.  This would explain the correct behavior when you are passing over single rectangles.  When you are passing over more than one rectangle, the depth correction is being fired multiple times, causing jitter.

Comment: That was it. All I had to add was break; to stop the for cycle.

Comment: Congrats on fixing it ;)

Comment: This is a bit puzzling. The original platformer sample iterates over *all* colliding blocks without jitter - in fact it does so purposely in order to resolve multiple collisions. And even though you were adjusting the position more than once, these adjustments were all done in the *same* update iteration so the played would never see any of the intermediate state. My gut instinct can't help but think that breaking early might turn up causing problems for *other* corner cases where the player needs to be pushed out of more than one colliding block. But I still can't figure out what's different.

Comment: I think what needs to be done, is verify if there is still a collision after the player's position has been adjusted.  If there is, then continue processing the collisions and if not, then you can break out.